# finding out how many array elements I am getting from a file (Dont know lists yet)

Tags: java, arrays, io

I need help making an array list so that I can find out how many elements an array needs for when I read them in from a text file. I have not learned how to do this yet and help would be much appreciated. I will show the parts of code that needs fixed as I get null if I don't have the correct stored in the array. This piece is what needs help but below it is the full code.

```
public static void output(tokens[], correct[], percentage[], letterGrade[], double      totalAVG, int highScore, int lowScore)
 { 
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Result.txt")) ;

for (int t=0 ; t< tokens.length ; t+=2 )
{   
    g = 0 ;
    pw.println(tokens[t] + "," + correct[g] + percentage[g] + letterGrade[g]) ;
    g++ ;
}
    pw.println("Average: " + totalAVG + "% (" + totalGrade + ")") ;
    pw.println("High Score: " + highScore*2) ;  
    pw.println("Low Score: " + lowScore*2) ;

pw.close() ;





import java.util.* ;
import java.io.* ;

public class Proj5 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) ;
```

/* This piece opens connections with the file, splits up each line, and then puts the 
pieces into an array (tokens). */

```
String[] tokens= information(fileCheck) ;
```

/*
*
* Opens connection to file with ids and answers and returns them split up. 
* @param (String a) pulls in the filename for use in method
* @return Returns an array containing the split-up file. */

```
public static String[] information(String a) throws IOException
{   
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File(a)) ; // opens connection with file
    String[] quarters = new String[] ;
    int index = 0 ;
    int lengthArray = 0 ;
    while (inFile.hasNext()) 
    {
        lengthArray++ ;
    }   
    while (inFile.hasNext())
```

// loops while more lines in file
        {

```
        String line = inFile.nextLine() ;           // brings in next line to be broken up
        String[] array = line.split(",") ;
        quarters[index] = array[0]  ;           //stores lines into array tokens
        index++ ;
        quarters[index] = array[1] ;
        index++ ;
    }       
        inFile.close() ;                            // close connection to file
        return quarters ;
} // end information
```

/**
* (Prints out the required information) *
* @param pulls in data array
* @param pulls in number correct array
* @param pulls in percentage correct array
* @param 
* (list all parameters, one per line)
* @return None */
public static void output(tokens[], correct[], percentage[], letterGrade[], double totalAVG, int highScore, int lowScore)
{ 
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Result.txt")) ;

```
for (int t=0 ; t< tokens.length ; t+=2 )
{   
    g = 0 ;
    pw.println(tokens[t] + "," + correct[g] + percentage[g] + letterGrade[g]) ;
    g++ ;
}
    pw.println("Average: " + totalAVG + "% (" + totalGrade + ")") ;
    pw.println("High Score: " + highScore*2) ;  
    pw.println("Low Score: " + lowScore*2) ;

pw.close() ;
```

} // end output

} // end class

Comment: Oh and the file it reads from has lines (Anywhere from 1-50) formatted like this 4563123,112211324135412.

Comment: Now _that's_ a wall of code!

Comment: They see me scrolling, they hating...

Comment: Please check http://sscce.org

Comment: But if he already knew how to narrow it down to a SSCCE, he wouldn't need help with his homework...

Comment: yeah sorry for posting the whole thing usually I dont then get asked too.

Comment: I cut it down thanks for posting the SSCCE link SJuan76 It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im too short to climb that wall. I will give you an example of an ArrayList though:

```
ArrayList<String> dinosaur = new ArrayList<String>(); // <String> is an explicit type declaration


    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    int i=0;
    try 
    {
      // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
      FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file.txt");

      //create buffered reader obj 
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

//while not EOF, store line in array element
      while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine ()) != null) {

        dinosaur.add(line);

        i++;
      }


      // Always close files.
      bufferedReader.close();
    }
    //handle exceptions
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
      System.out.println("Unable to open file" + e);
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    {
      System.out.println("Error reading file" + e);
    }
```

This will read each line from a text file and store it as a string in an ArrayList (Although List is more commonly preferred). An ArrayList is dynamic so you don't need to know how many elements you will store (the number of lines in a file)... as long as there's enough memory in the stack to handle it all :p

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approaches:

1) is to read the file in advance, counting how many lines it has (for example using a scanner's HasNextLine ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine() ) and then you can initialize the array to be that large and count it again.

2) is to use a collection such as `ArrayList<String>` and simply add lines to it as you iterate through the file. ArrayList automatically resizes to have as many or as few entries as you need, so you don't have to worry in advance about how many lines the file countains. Using it is conceptually the same as an array - `[i]` works on an ArrayList fine, as well as methods like `add` and `remove` which change the number of entries in the ArrayList rather than editing one that is already there.